# Coefficients output in R without alphabetical stacked-up default

Tags: r, format, output, regression, coefficients

Both in `lm()` as in `glm` or in `lmer` the default output for coefficients is to  format them as as an (Intercept) corresponding to the variable with the highest alphabet order, followed by the rest of the coefficients. To find out the actual value of any coefficient, it is necessary to add (or subtract) from the (Intercept) baseline and, depending on the model, multiple intermediate coefficients.

Although this is not a problem when using just a couple of regressors, it is cumbersome and prone to error in more complex models. For example:

For the data:

```
head(trees)
  site tree treatment organ sample tissue   length
1    L LT01         T  root      1 phloem  90.9924
2    L LT01         T  root      1  xylem 123.4933
3    L LT01         T  root      2 phloem 101.2444
4    L LT01         T  root      2  xylem 106.0529
5    L LT01         T  root      3 phloem 108.8453
6    L LT01         T  root      3  xylem 126.5165
```

The call:

```
fit <- lmer(length ~ treatment + organ + tissue + (1|tree/organ/sample), data = trees) 
summary(fit)
Random effects:
 Groups              Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
 sample:(organ:tree) (Intercept) 1.035e-12 1.017e-06
 organ:tree          (Intercept) 0.000e+00 0.000e+00
 tree                (Intercept) 8.796e+00 2.966e+00
 Residual                        8.873e+01 9.420e+00
Number of obs: 360, groups:  sample:(organ:tree), 180; organ:tree, 60; tree, 30

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  93.7903     1.2539  58.4000  74.798  < 2e-16 ***
treatmentT   13.5571     1.4692  28.0000   9.227 5.51e-10 ***
organstem     8.1326     0.9929 328.0000   8.191 5.77e-15 ***
tissuexylem  13.9814     0.9929 328.0000  14.081  < 2e-16 ***
```

yields coefficients expressed in a highly dependent way, which makes the quick calculation of any one of them tedious.

Is there a way of getting the actual coefficients, at least for the fixed effects, in a more straightforward format?

Comment: What exactly is your desired ouptput? And are you sure you need to add or substract?

Comment: You could use `predict` for this. E.g., `predict(fit, newdata = data.frame(treatment = "T", organ = "stem", tissue = "xylem"), re.form = NA)`. Use `expand.grid` to get all group means. You could probably also use package `lsmeans`.